# Can I download a free app from the App Store without a credit card?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

I just recently got an iPod Touch and wanted to download some free apps. The App Store wanted me to get an Apple ID, no problem. But now it's telling me to input a credit card. I don't have one, and anyway shouldn't need one to download free apps.

I did some searching here and on Google and found out that there should be a "None" option when selecting credit cards, but it was not there. I then read that it's disabled in some countried, so I tried telling iTunes that I'm in the US (I'm in Argentina), but still no "None" option. Later, I read that apparently this feature was disabled in iTunes 10, so I installed iTunes 9, but I still don't get the option.

How can I get the No Credit Card option to appear when downloading an app for the first time? It doesn't make sense that you should need a credit card for free stuff.

EDIT: To clarify, I already made an account in Apple's website, I'm looking for a way to be able to select "None" when buying an app through iTunes.

Comment: Did you try to buy a free app and *then* clicked on the "create new account" button or did you try directly creating a new account? The "None" option only appears in the first case, as far as I know.

Comment: I think I tried to download an app and saw that I needed an account, so I went to the Apple website and made one and then I tried again and had to select a credit card.

Comment: There are many reasons why this might happen. If the answers here don't work, check the KB and explanation here. http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/125846

Comment: For a pre-existing AppleID, change country to USA, select Paypal, cancel the Paypal login, then "None" is available. Then use desktop itunes to change country and street address back to what they should be. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139634/44901

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get an app for free (if you didn't get the choice to pick None as payment option) you should open your installed ITunes program. Then from within the program go to ITunes Store and pick any free app and try to buy it (Google Translate or some other one). It will tell you to login/register into ITunes. **If you create account from there** you will have a choice to pick None as payment option.

This worked for me several times for my customers.

Comment: Sadly, not anymore :)

Comment: I did this like 2 weeks ago when my collegues got an IPhones.

Comment: How is this different from what I already did?

Comment: You just went and created new account. What you need to do is you need to install itunes and then enter the Store.. find some free app and try to download it.. it will tell you to login/create new account. Do so and you will have option "none". You have to do all that from ITunes not from Apple website or anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Maybe the question isn't clear, I'll edit.

Comment: I'll accept this answer if you make it clear that the account needs to be **created** from iTunes and not from the Apple website for the "None" option to appear, because that's what happened.

Comment: Edited to be more clear.

Comment: Ok, I discard my comment from Mar 14. It seems that you must fully register by "buying" a free app. If you previously had an account for example with apple dev center, you cannot select the None option no matter what.

Comment: I've even attempted creating extra accounts from other e-mail addresses and the none option is simply not available, even done the way detailed above.

Answer (score 2):

Buy an Apple iTunes Gift Card for $10 and redeem it in your iTunes account. That should satisfy their internal logic and allow you to download free items (and obviously buy items if you wanted to). After I my account was hacked from China (long story, don't ask), I removed my credit card and added some money via an iTunes gift card so if it got hacked again, they couldn't buy an excessive amount of content.

Comment: Well, ideally I shouldn't have to pay more for this; they're free apps, after all.