# Do I need a credit card to install free apps on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I'm using MacBook pro. My problem is: every time when I want to download an app it's asking about my credit card information. I used to have a credit card but I don't have it now. I can't even download free apps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I download a free app from the App Store without a credit card?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10180/can-i-download-a-free-app-from-the-app-store-without-a-credit-card)

Comment: @Buscar웃 possibly but it's also possible the Mac App Store behaves differently from the iOS App Store in this regard. Leaving it open.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open **iTunes.**
2. From the Menu Bar, select **Store > My account.** You will be prompted for your Apple ID and Password. Enter it.
3. Under **“Payment Type”** click the **“Edit”** link.
4. Select **“None”** and then click **“Done”**

This will enable you to download free items without needing to provide any financial information. Obviously, if you want to purchase an app in the future, you’ll need to update your payment method.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to exist any more (June 2019)

Answer (score 0):

Open the appstore on your iDevice (or iTunes on the Computer) to something like *only use gift-cards*. Then you won't need any credit card.

Comment: as it stands (July 2019), you seem to need a gift card to do that. ie: you need to put money in you apple account. sigh!